# How to implement double click in HDL M/S 24 module

Tags: knx

I have HDL M/S 24 dry contacts module. Using it I'm planning to control light groups, blinds, scenes etc.

I've managed to configure single click and long click but how could I also achieve double clicking with that particular device? 
This will increase my control freedom and require less wall switches.

I've tried to use counter switch channel type but I don't think this is the one. 
Also I though about using external logic function (I have Zennio device with built in logic) but actually haven't figure out how to correctly configure it for this job without knowing timestamp.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

PS: I want to hear about KNX way to make it rock solid. In case there is no way I will just use Node-Red instead.